# How do I write this conditional statement for a nested resource in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three models: User Poll PollItem Vote

A user has many polls and votes

Poll has many poll items(nested attributes) and belongs to user

Poll item has many votes and belongs to poll

Votes belong to poll item and User

I already made a voting feature where a user can vote/unvote poll items. Now, I am trying to write a conditional statement so that a user will be able to vote on just a poll item within a poll. For example, if a vote has already been recorded for the first poll item within a poll then I want the vote link be disabled on other poll items within the poll except for the one voted on.

```
<% if current_user.votes.where(poll: @poll).count > 0 %>
    display vote link
<% else %>
    remove vote link
<% end %>
```

But I get the error
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: votes.poll_id

Please suggest a better title to the question too.

EDIT:

As suggested by @lam, I adjusted the statement to

```
<% if user_signed_in? && Vote.where(user_id: current_user.id).where(poll_item_id: @poll.poll_items.pluck(:id)).count > 0 %>
    <p>You have voted</p>
    <%= link_to "Unvote", poll_poll_item_vote_path(@poll, @poll_item), method: :delete %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to "Vote", poll_poll_item_vote_path(@poll, @poll_item), method: :post %>
<% end %>
```

However, the action got performed on all the poll items in a poll. When I voted on a poll item, the vote links on other poll items changed instead of the voted item.

Answer (score 0):

if `Votes belong to poll item and User` then the Vote should has `poll_item_id`, not `poll_id`. So i guess the logic like this:

```rb
<% if user_signed_in? && Vote.where(user_id: current_user.id, poll_item_id: @poll_item.id).count > 0 %>
    <p>You have voted</p>
    <%= link_to "Unvote", poll_poll_item_vote_path(@poll, @poll_item), method: :delete %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to "Vote", poll_poll_item_vote_path(@poll, @poll_item), method: :post %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I appreciate your contribution. However, the action was performed on all the poll items in a poll. When I clicked on "vote", all the vote links on the items changed to "unvote" instead of the one that was voted on. I have updated the question with details of this, please check.

Comment: @TolaseAdegbite, if you voted on any `poll item` of a `poll` then you expect that all `poll item` of that `poll` show "unvote" ?

Comment: No, I want just the poll item that was voted on to show "unvote" but in the present case voting on a poll item in a poll changes other "vote" links to "unvote". Please let me know if you need me to show more codes.

Comment: @TolaseAdegbite i updated my answer but i recommend that you should read & practice this guide: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html